# How to move document from document library to subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have a document library with documents. And there is a subsite with the same list. I want to move the documents from the part library to the subsite library.

Is this possible to do with the powershell `.MoveTo()` command?

Error is

```
Exception calling "MoveTo" with "2" argument(s): "Folder "MyLib" does not exist."
At C:\script\archive3.ps1:131 char:27
+             $spFile.MoveTo <<<< ($destLoc, $true);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: Can you include your code as well?

Comment: code is requirement or you can do it via GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with `SPFile.MoveTo()`.

`MoveTo()` is limited to the same site only (see remark in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms468280.aspx)). So, if you want to move file to the subsite you have to that with some more code.

And indeed the error message is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the .moveTo() command specifically but you can script the action. Review the answer posted to a similar question here:
[Move files between document libraries in the same Site Collection (#2)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43737/move-files-between-document-libraries-in-the-same-site-collection-2)

You may also want to just consider opening each library in windows explorer and just manually moving those items (if it's just a one time operation).

Comment: Does it have to be in same site? Cause I'm moving to subsite