# 2007 - Copying file from library to another not keeping metadata

Tags: document-library, 2007

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I'm trying to copy files from a document library to another.

I've created the new document library from a saved model based on the old library, so I've the same columns, same views etc.

Then with "Windows explorer" I've copied files between the two libraries.

The problem is that many files did not keep the metadata/columns values or they get the default value of a column. Is that a normal behaviour?

How can I do to copy files keeping these values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is expected behavior. If you want to preserve metadata you should consider purchasing a third party migration tool like Sharegate. It will make moving files, sites, libraries faster and easier. It will also preserve things like metadata and permissions.

Comment: thanks! the solution suggested here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43739/20605 could be another way to do the copy?